# Find image src by alt in Gatling

Tags: gatling

I'm trying to extract img src value which can be found by alt value.

```
.check(css("img", "src").saveAs("src")))
```

This shows first img value from html body.

Answer (score 1):

Should be:

```scala
.check(css("""img[alt="YOUR_VALUE"]""", "src").saveAs("src")))
```

You would fine this information in any CSS selector tutorial such as [this one](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp).